# JavaScript increase/decrease values in Hangman

Tags: javascript

I am making a Hangman game in JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. I am stuck on trying to get the wins variable to increase by 1 after all the letters have been guessed correctly and have the guesses decrease by 1 after each letter is guessed.

I also think that I need to incorporate this line of code but everywhere I try to insert it, the game breaks:

```
// Set the inner HTML contents of the #game div to our html string
    document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML = html;
```

My code:

```
//Array of available words
    const words = ["patriots", "bills", "dolphins", "jets", "chiefs", "chargers", "raiders", "broncos", "steelers", "ravens", "bengals", "browns", "jaguars", "titans", "colts", "texans", "eagles", "cowboys", "redskins", "giants", "rams", "seahawks", "cardinals", "niners", "vikings", "lions", "packers", "bears", "saints", "panthers", "falcons", "buccaneers"];

   let currentWord;
   let dashes = [];
   let rightLetter = [];
   let wrongLetter = [];

// Creating variables to hold the number of wins and guesses remaining
    let wins = 0;
    let guesses = 10;

// Creating a variable to hold our new HTML. Our HTML now keeps track of the user and computer guesses, and wins/losses/ties.
    let html =
    "<p>wins: " + wins + "</p>" +
    "<p>guesses: " + guesses + "</p>";



//Click button to start game
    document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click",function(){
        startGame("")
    })

//Computer chooses a random word from the words array. The random choice becomes currentWord
    function startGame(){
        currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];


//Creates underscores depending on length of the currentWord; push underscores to dashes array 
        for ( let i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++ ) {
            dashes.push(' _ ');


        }

        writeWordDashes(dashes.join(' '))
    }

    function writeWordDashes(str){
        document.querySelector("#dashContainer").innerHTML = str;
    }


//HTML document waits for key to be pressed; key is assiged Unicode value (a/A are diff)
        document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
            let codes = event.keyCode;

//Convert a Unicode value into a character
            let characters = String.fromCharCode(codes);

//Search currentWord for the users correct guess; push character to rightLetter array
            if(currentWord.indexOf(characters) > -1)
            rightLetter.push(characters);


//Replace dashes with correctly choosen characters
            dashes[currentWord.indexOf(characters)] = characters;

//Loop over word and replace dashes
            for( let i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
                let currentLetter = currentWord[i];
            if (currentLetter === characters) {
                dashes[i] = characters;
            }
        }

//Write words to dashes
            writeWordDashes (dashes.join(''))


//Search currentWord for the users incorrect guess; push character to wrongLetter array
            if(currentWord.indexOf(characters) < 0)
            wrongLetter.push(characters);

            document.querySelector(".wrong").innerHTML = wrongLetter;   
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

-- EDIT --

So, some explanations about what I did/added, and why.

You should avoid creating html with string concatenation if possible. And in your case, It would make sense, that you create the html elements before-hand and then populate them via document.getElementById('wins') or document.querySelector('wins').
If you do insist, that you keep your current implementation, then you need to put the .container somewhere ( ... ), but then you would need to update the container every time, there is a relevant change to the contents (possibly encapsulating inside a function), most likely update would be the guessing part.

Next, since the game needed to increase the win variable, there needs to be a winning scenario. For that we need a new variable, that states whether the game is active (otherwise you could keep winning/losing).
Every key press, a guess is made. With each guess it is checked, that maybe the game has been won. In this case doing a check, whether the dashes contains a ' _ ', and if it doesn't, then -1 is returned and the game is won.
With each keystroke, it is checked, whether the letter is in the word or not. If it is not, then guesses is increased. Future version could also allow a fixed number of guesses, before ending the game.

-- EDIT --

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="dashContainer"></div>
<div class="wrong"></div>
wins <div id="wins"></div>
losses <div id="losses"></div>
guesses <div id="guesses"></div>


<script>
  //Array of available words
  const words = ["patriots", "bills", "dolphins", "jets", "chiefs", "chargers", "raiders", "broncos", "steelers", "ravens", "bengals", "browns", "jaguars", "titans", "colts", "texans", "eagles", "cowboys", "redskins", "giants", "rams", "seahawks", "cardinals", "niners", "vikings", "lions", "packers", "bears", "saints", "panthers", "falcons", "buccaneers"];

  let currentWord;
  let dashes = [];
  let rightLetter = [];
  let wrongLetter = [];
  let gameActive = false;

  // Creating variables to hold the number of wins and guesses remaining
  let wins = 0;
  let losses = 0;
  let guesses = 0;

  // Creating a variable to hold our new HTML. Our HTML now keeps track of the user and computer guesses, and wins/losses/ties.
  function render() {
    document.querySelector('#wins').textContent = wins;
    document.querySelector('#losses').textContent = losses;
    document.querySelector('#guesses').textContent = guesses;
  }
  render();


  //Click button to start game
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    startGame("")

  })

  function checkWin() {
    if (!gameActive) return;

    if (dashes.indexOf(' _ ') < 0) {
      gameActive = false;
      wins += 1;
    }
  }

  //Computer chooses a random word from the words array. The random choice becomes currentWord
  function startGame() {
    gameActive = true;
    currentWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    wrongLetter = [];
    rightLetter = [];
    guesses = 0;
    dashes = [];
    //Creates underscores depending on length of the currentWord; push underscores to dashes array
    for (let i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
      dashes.push(' _ ');
    }

    writeWordDashes(dashes.join(' '))
  }

  function writeWordDashes(str) {
    document.querySelector("#dashContainer").innerHTML = str;
  }


  //HTML document waits for key to be pressed; key is assiged Unicode value (a/A are diff)
  document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (!gameActive) return;
    let codes = event.keyCode;

    //Convert a Unicode value into a character
    let characters = String.fromCharCode(codes);

    //Search currentWord for the users correct guess; push character to rightLetter array
    if (currentWord.indexOf(characters) > -1)
      rightLetter.push(characters);


    //Replace dashes with correctly choosen characters
    dashes[currentWord.indexOf(characters)] = characters;

    //Loop over word and replace dashes
    for (let i = 0; i < currentWord.length; i++) {
      let currentLetter = currentWord[i];
      if (currentLetter === characters) {
        dashes[i] = characters;
      }
    }

    //Write words to dashes
    writeWordDashes(dashes.join(''))


    //Search currentWord for the users incorrect guess; push character to wrongLetter array
    if (currentWord.indexOf(characters) < 0) {
      if (wrongLetter.indexOf(characters) < 0) {
        wrongLetter.push(characters);
        guesses += 1;
      }
    }
    document.querySelector(".wrong").innerHTML = wrongLetter;
    checkWin();
    render();
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code as your answer. Please edit your question and add an explanation.

Comment: Can you explain what was changed and why? A code dump doesn't help anybody.